# Paginating a Dataframe to display limited results when GET method is called

Tags: python, dataframe, flask, pagination, postman

I have dataframe which includes ***df = [productId, product_name, price]***. There are many records in it and all I want is to read limited number  of records(let's say 10 records at a time) using postman. I am using python and Flask to create the API and I have already tried django pagination and it didn't work for me.